# Java Spring Boot: Runnable Thread Class running despite being commented

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, runnable

I have encountered an interesting yet a terrifying situation. My application has two features namely, `OtpListener` and `CdmMonitor` running on two separate threads. For now, only the `OtpListener` feature was required so I commented out `CdmMonitor` in the main class.

However, I still see the logs for the commented out class `CdmMonitorService`. This service was running (when it shouldn't as it was commented)

Do threads implemented from the `Runnable` class operate this way? I did not find anything of the sort in its documentation.

**Main Class**: `OtpTrackerApp.java`

```
package dev.xfoil.otpTracker;

import dev.xfoil.otpTracker.service.CdmMonitorService;
import dev.xfoil.otpTracker.service.OTPListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"dev.xfoil.otpTracker.*","dev.xfoil.shared.*", "dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.*", "dev.xfoil.shared.dal.entities.*","dev.xfoil.shared.dal.cache.*"})
public class OtpTrackerApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    public OTPListener otpListener;

//    @Autowired
//    public CdmMonitorService cdmMonitorService;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(OtpTrackerApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
//        Thread monitoringThread = new Thread(cdmMonitorService);
//        monitoringThread.start();
        otpListener.startListening();
    }
}
```

**CdmMonitorService.java**

```
package dev.xfoil.otpTracker.service;

import com.google.common.flogger.FluentLogger;
import dev.xfoil.otpTracker.firebase.FirestoreManager;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.MachineMonitorRepo;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.MachineOperationsHistoryRepo;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.MachinesRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class CdmMonitorService implements Runnable {
    FluentLogger logger = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();

    @Autowired
    MachineMonitorRepo machineMonitorRepo;

    @Autowired
    MachineOperationsHistoryRepo machineOperationsHistoryRepo;

    @Autowired
    MachinesRepo machinesRepo;

    @Autowired
    FirestoreManager firestoreManager;

    public CdmMonitorService() {
    }
    
    @Override
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 120000l)
    public void run() {
        try {
            // code removed for brevity
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.atWarning().log("Exception in CDM Monitor Thread " + e);
        }
    }


}
```

**OtpListener.java**

```
package dev.xfoil.otpTracker.service;

import com.google.common.flogger.FluentLogger;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.entities.AccountLedger;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.models.OTP;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.LedgerRepo;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.NoteCountRepo;
import dev.xfoil.shared.dal.repositories.springdata.UtilRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
@Service
public class OTPListener {
    private static final FluentLogger logger = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();
    @Autowired
    UtilRepo utilRepo;

    @Autowired
    ThirdPartyApiCalls discordServer;

    @Autowired
    NoteCountRepo noteCountRepo;

    private static LocalDateTime latestOTPTime;


    @Value("#{${webhooks}}")
    HashMap<String, String> discordLink = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @PostConstruct
    public LocalDateTime getLatestOTPTimestamp() {
        latestOTPTime = utilRepo.getTimeOfLatestOTP();
        return latestOTPTime;
    }
    
    public void startListening() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.atInfo().log("Current in-mem links:");
        try {
        // code commented for brevity
                Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, `CdmMonitorService` is still annotated as a service and has a scheduled method so Spring will pick it up and execute that method regularly. That also means starting an explicit thread in your main class is not the way to handle things like this.

Comment: Interesting, runs even though its not Autowired for usage. What is the best way to to multi-thread from main? I mean, what implicit methods are there?

Comment: In a Spring application you let the container (i.e. Spring) handle threading so you basically just annotate methods you want to be executed at certain times, i.e. scheduled, at startup, when certain events happen etc. - Autowiring is meant to get a reference to the component/service and doesn't mean that component has to be autowired somewhere in your code for it to be run.

Comment: On another note, the way `CdmMonitorService.run()` would be executed with a gap of 2 minutes in between which seems to indicate a couple of errors: 1) you should not add `Thread.sleep()` here since the thread that executes the task would then be blocked to do something else and those 10 seconds you have there add to the delay of the next execution ...

Comment: ... 2) a monitoring service is normally executed regularly, i.e. it would seem you want yours to run every 2 minutes. However, that would require you to use `fixedRate`. `fixedDelay` is the time between the end of the last execution and the start of the next, i.e. with your code each execution would take at least 10 seconds (due to the sleep) so the 2nd run would start at least 2:10 after the 1st (start of next execution = length of previous execution + fixed delay).

Comment: Thank you for your response 1) This blocking was intentional so as to avoid a race conditon that might arise when persisting data to the DB.

Comment: 2) is very much valid. But the time delay isn't a big of a concern here since the service is to be run periodically - what matters that it runs in intervals no matter how spaced those intervals be

Comment: Tbh, throwing a delay into some code in order to avoid a race condition looks like a design smell to me. You probably might want to rethink your approach here, e.g. if you need to wait until some other service added some data then that service could publish an event when the data has been added and have your monitoring service listen to it. Here's a nice entry tutorial to Spring events: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events